# How to set the default location service as OFF in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

Where can I change default location mode in AOSP.

I have to set the location service as OFF.
I have checked this file

> /frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml

but I couldn't find any variation by changing values.

Is there a centralized file/folder for all the settings?

Comment: You may want to try to find the code which *uses* the value too.   What have you done to make sure you incorporated the change in the build, and are starting from a clean slate in your test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a XML file at [`/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/defaults.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r34/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/defaults.xml) where you can set default values.

To set default location provider you would need to set [`def_location_providers_allowed`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r34/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/defaults.xml#47). AOSP's default value is `gps`, but you can set `network` for network location provider or anything else to disable it.

Comment: Yes, It is working now.

To disable the location provider I put the tag as empty. As there is no default location provider the location will be off.

Comment: this does not seem to work for Android 11 unfortunately.